# Force.com IDE Plugin not appearing in Eclipse

Tags: ide, eclipse, mac-os-x

I am running:
OSX El Capitan (Version 10.11.4)
Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2
Java SE 8 [1.8.0_73]

I have installed the Force.com IDE plugin in Eclipse as per the guide but the Force.com plugin does not appear in perspectives or the New File/Project drop down. I have tried Java SE 6 & Java SE 7 and it does not appear to make any difference. I have also had a thorough look through Google but other than trying different Java versions I cannot find any  other reasons or solutions to try.

Anyone got any idea why this is not appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to delete this post as I figured it out 20 mins after posting but alas someone may find this useful.

Coming from a Windows machine where Kepler ran Force.com the "smoothest" I installed Kepler on OSX without reading through the recommended installation version.

After reading that you should be installed 4.x I upgraded to the latest (I believe Mars 2), installed the plugin again and there it was... success!!

Hope this helps someone.